# Stop SSRS From Hiding Columns

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

How do I stop SSRS from hiding a column when previewing if the column has nothing more than empty rows? I have set all columns to be fully visible, yet the report preview does not show the empty columns. I know that this is a default feature within Visual Studio that hides all empty columns by default, so how do I change it so it can show all columns no matter what. Where can I change those settings?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the preview in the query designer of the dataset:
This is only possible when writing your own MDX since the generated code always generates a `SELECT NON EMPTY` for the measure axis. So removing the `NON EMPTY` part will always show your column/measure.

If you mean the ssrs report preview:
Columns only hide when using a table matrix with a column group. In this case make sure your dataset always returns each column group at least once, regardless of your chosen filters. E.g. if using MDX this could mean removing a `NON EMPTY` from your row axis or using the right-click option "include empty cells".

**Clarification for comment plus possible workaround**:
This "hiding columns" things is no feature. If the column isn't in the result of the dataset, SSRS can't know that this value even exists, so there is no solution if using a column group except for redesigning your query.

You could work around this by not using a column group and instead of using static "hard-coded" columns which, for example, sum the values depending on your group. See the following example screenshot i made: [example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/40jj2.png)

Comment: Yes, I am doing the second option. All columns that are being hidden are grouped and have filters. The thing is that sometimes the dataset does return data to those columns and sometimes they do not. I see that SSRS will not show columns that are empty, so is there is way to remove that feature, so columns can always show no matter what?

Comment: Updated the answer with a possible workaround, though this may not be practical if you have many too many columns in your column group.

Comment: Okay that updated comment just fixed my issue. I ended duplicating the columns and added an expression to the new column for where if the original column was 0 (meaning it was blank so it was hidden) then show me a 0, else just show me the value, and in the end just set the original columns to be hidden at all times no matter what. This way the duplicate columns will always be visible, and they will only show the value from the original columns. It's a great method to solve the issue, and might be used by anyone else if they also have this same issue.